# What is the difference between -f and -s options in If condition?

Tags: unix, if-statement

What is the difference between `-f` and `-s` Option in If condition

Mainly how they are different in functionality?

I know the google meaning of these but want to know the practical use.

Answer (score 11):

From `man test`:

```
-f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file

-s FILE
          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

#### Example

Let's create a file from scratch and check it out.

```
$ touch b
```

Does the file exist?

```
$ [ -f "b" ] && echo "file exists"
file exists                          # yes!!!!
```

Does the file have a size greater than zero?

```
$ [ -s "b" ] && echo "file exists and is greater than zero"
$                                    # no!!!!
```

---

So a good `if-elif-else` condition to check the existence of a file could be:

```
if [ -s "$file" ]; then
   echo "exists and it is not empty"
elif [ -f "$file" ]; then
   echo "at least exists"
else
   echo "does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Lol... I almost typed the same and saw your frequent edits... You won :)

Comment: Haha @realspirituals we must be soul mates :D